# Jetbrains Pycharm 2019.2 & Win10 WSL: can't not sync actual python package

Tags: python, linux, pycharm, remote-debugging, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm here to look for help. Recently I need to do some linux-based development so I try a brand new way to archive this:using WSL instead of SSH interpreter. Vmware performance is not so good on my 8GB laptop, so I try to WSL. When talking about SSH Interpreter, I think SSH Interpreter has been a little heavy when you meet WSL for the first time just like me.

WSL has many benefits, such as automatic fill local path as remote path and need no virtual machine or VPS.
But something funny happens: I'm using Kali-Linux as my Windows subsystem of Linux and python3.7 is installed as default. WSL has two account:girl and root, and I add interpreter by choose WSL:

[image: WSL Interpreter]

Then show the package status:
[image: Package status that proved to be correct]
As shown from the above, there is no package name bs4 BUT when I type `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`, pycharm did not warn me that I do not have the package:
[image: seen to be have this package but actually is not]
Even run this script will return an error:
[image: honestly return an error]

And I don't know why. Once upon a time I install `rsync` on the subsystem and it appears to be health. However I still have some doubut so I try to confirm whether the problem is solved or not. I uninstall another package and try to import it. The same circumstance occurs again.

Jetbrains did not give any answer, will anyone here know why is that? Thank you very much.
(ps:have not try other WSL version yet, pycharm version is professional and registered)